# AngularJS ui-select optimization

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select

I have many (around 70, forms dynamically) [ui-select (multiple)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) elements and every is filled with the same data.

```
<tr ng-repeat="entities in value">
    <td>{{entities.ourTag.displayName}}</td>
    <td>
       <ui-select multiple
            ng-model="entities.thairTag" theme="select2"
            ng-disabled="disabled" on-remove="onSelectCallback()"
            on-select="onSelectCallback()">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select tag...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices 
             group-by="groupByCategory" repeat="thairTag in thairTags | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} track by $index">
        <div
            ng-bind-html="thairTag.name | highlight: $select.search" />
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select></td>
</tr>
```

Calling `group-by` on every iteration make my page load up to 5 seconds and if I'll remove it it will make this process twice faster so my thoughts was to call it on ui-select click. Any ideas how could I do this or may be additional ways to optimize this solution? Quick example of what it looks like is [here](http://plnkr.co/3jqMFDa5S1SgZY9LErrz).
Also bindonce with `repeat="thairTag in ::thairTags"` is not working.

Comment: If someone experiencing same issue i found some workaround, so options for each select are populated on its call (clicking on drop-down arrow).